I want to format Text in water wave structure, with repeating values and looping from right to left
enter image description here
As you can see in the image - I want to achieve the yellow line structure. I tried to search many article, blogs but eventually I got nothing related to my problem.
If you could help me provide article for this kind of problem I would appreciate it.
If you could provide me with a bit of code structure to begin with and related article I would really appreciate your time.
Thank you for your time. And sorry if i am wrong in any sense as it is my first question on stackOverflow.

@DBS this wouldn't be the solution since he is asking for a "looping/animating wavy structure" rather than it being static.

Nothing in the question implies animation is required to me, but if that is the case, the same approach + animation has a duplicate here: How To Make Text Move back and Forth On a Curved Path HTML CSS

Thank you DBS and Tanishq S, both the links do help me with my problem. Thank you for your time.

Perhaps you may use SVG


<svg width="500" height="500">
    <path id="curvePath" d="M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 Q 340,140 400,30" fill="transparent" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="20px"/>
    <text width="500" dy="5px">
        <textPath href="#curvePath">
            This is a text following a yellow wavey line all the way to the end..!
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>




This helps a lot. Thank you for your time and answer Redu.
